# Is Honeycomb only for tablets?

Tags: android, mobile

I know this to some people might sound very stupid question, but is Honeycomb only for tablets? I am making a thesis project developing an Android app for mobile: which version would you suggest I should use? The one that is most popular, I guess?

Comment: Honeycub? Do you mean Honeycomb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. currently only for tablets. However the goal is combining the phone and tablet os on the next release, named Icecream Sandwich. It was also said at Google I/O that there will be a Gingerbread release bringing some features from Honeycomb.

Comment: Would you suggest I should use the Gingerbread 2.3 to develop my app?

Comment: well to aim most of the market it is best to develop for 2.1, if you want to aim whole market you need to stick to 1.6. Unless you need something from a newer version always try to use the lowest available to target more users and devices. The best is designing your app for the lowest version and enabling newer apis and functionalities programatically if they are available on the device.

Answer (score 2):

See the chart published by google at http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html.
This will give you an idea of which platform to develop for.

Answer (score 0):

Gingerbread 2.3.3 is most popular to develop for right now, it has few new APIs that supported hardware acceleration. And Android Ice Cream Sandwich has backward compatible support for older Android SDK .